# Formulate a z-test into a general linear model

Tags: regression, generalized-linear-model, t-test, z-test, centering

I've heard it said that most statistical tests can be reformulated within the GLM framework. I can see how that can be done with a two-sample t-test (dummy code group membership and interpret the slope as the difference between the two group means). Is it possible to reformulate a z-test (or a one-sample t) into the GLM framework?

My initial thoughts for a one-sample t are as follows: you could center the variable of interest around $\mu$ then do an intercept-only model and test whether $\beta_0$ has a mean other than zero.

And, it seems that is the case:

```
set.seed(1)
    #### set up population values
mu = 100
sd = 15

    #### simulate a one-sample with a different mean
new.iq = rnorm(30, 105, 15)
    #### center the data according to mu
new.iq.centered = new.iq-mu

    #### run a regression and a t-test
summary(lm(new.iq.centered~1))
t.test(new.iq, mu=100)
```

Both yield the same t statistic, df, estimate (after retransforming back into the original metric), and p-values:

```
> summary(lm(new.iq.centered~1))

Call:
lm(formula = new.iq.centered ~ 1)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-34.457  -7.761   2.612   9.394  22.692 

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)  
(Intercept)    6.237      2.531   2.464   0.0199 *
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 13.86 on 29 degrees of freedom

> t.test(new.iq, mu=100)

    One Sample t-test

data:  new.iq
t = 2.4644, df = 29, p-value = 0.01989
alternative hypothesis: true mean is not equal to 100
95 percent confidence interval:
 101.0608 111.4130
sample estimates:
mean of x 
 106.2369
```

But how would you do this with a z-test. Short of side-stepping the estimation of the test statistic (and manually inserting a value for $\sigma\{b_0\}$), and manually specifying a z-distribution, I see no way of doing it. Or am I missing something?

Comment: It depends on what you mean by the "GLM framework."  Your question seems to equate that with a particular software application that *by default* applies t tests.  But there is nothing at all in the concept of a GLM that precludes conducting z tests.  Is your question really about how to fool `lm` into producing the output of a z-test?

Comment: No, not a particular software package. I'm talking about regression, I suppose. You can, for example, use regression to do an ANOVA or a t-test. Can you use a regression to do a z-test (whether using R, SAS, SPSS, matlab, by hand, or whatever)?

Comment: It's unclear what you mean.  Regression and testing are somewhat separate things, so first, what exactly do you mean by "use regression"?  What hypothesis do you plan to test?

Comment: Let me describe why I'm asking this question. I teach a graduate level stats class and for them, ANOVA and regression are two totally different procedures (ANOVA for categorical predictors and regression for quantitative predictors). I plan on doing an illustration showing how you can use dummy coding in a regression and get identical mean estimates, test statistic estimates, and p-values as you would in regression. I would love to also show that t-tests can be performed in regression (as I've done in the R code above). I'm asking whether we can do the same for z-tests. Make sense?

Comment: I still cannot understand what you're asking for, because of course one can perform either test in either circumstance: the only difference consists in whether you use a normal distribution or a t distribution to compute the p-value for the test statistic.

Comment: There's two differences, actually. Not only the distribution (normal versus t), but also the denominator of the test statistic. A t uses the computed standard deviation and a z uses the population standard deviation (which comes from sources beyond the dataset). Either way, it seems you can't use regression to test whether a dataset differs from a known population (which has a known mean and standard deviation). Right?